# Parsing the information of a URL out of a HTML <a></a> tags in C

Tags: c, parsing, text

My application gets as part of its data a large html formatted file that contains large amounts of links. Something like what you would get if you search anything on Google or Yahoo or other search engines: a list of URLs and the description or other text.

I've been trying to come out with a function that can parse the URL and the description and save them into a text file but it's proven hard, at least to me. So, if I have:

`<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>`

I would parse `http://www.w3schools.com` and `Visit W3Schools` and save them in a file.

Any way to achieve this? in plain C?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the HTML is truly just `<a href...>...</a>` then you can use XSL. Otherwise, you will need a complete HTML parser. Perhaps even a shell script + **Lynx** (a text-based browser) + **awk**. If this is a one-time task, then I'd search/replace in an editor. (Again, presuming well-formed XHTML.)

Comment: this is just a simple html file. the <a></a> is just that. Now, I don't want to use libraries or external html parsers. I just want to read the file and parse out the URL and the description.

Comment: The primary reason it's proven hard for you is that you're trying to do it in C. C is really, really, *really* not built for this kind of task. Newer languages provide much more sophisticated tools for string manipulation. C doesn't even have a real text type built in; when you use char\* and char[N], you're faking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need a proper html parser, but for something quick and dirty, try:

```
bool get_url(char **data, char **url, char **desc)
{
  bool result = false;
  char *ptr = strstr(*data, "<a");

  if(NULL != ptr)
  {
    *data = ptr + 2;

    ptr = strstr(*data, "href=\"");
    if(NULL != ptr)
    {
      *data = ptr + 6;
      *url = *data;

      ptr = strchr(*data, '"');
      if(NULL != ptr)
      {
        *ptr = '\0';
        *data = ptr + 1;

        ptr = strchr(*data, '>');
        if(NULL != ptr)
        {
          *data = ptr + 1;
          *desc = *data;

          ptr = strstr(*data, "</a>");
          if(NULL != ptr)
          {
            *ptr = '\0';
            *data = ptr + 4;
            result = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Not that `data` gets updated to be beyond the data parsed (it's an in-out parameter) and that the string passed in gets modified. I'm feeling lazy/too busy to do full solutions with memory allocated return strings.

Also you probably ought to return errors on the cascade of close scope braces (except the first one) which is partly why I stacked them up like that. There are other neater solutions that can be adapted to be more generic.

So basically you then call the function repeatedly until it returns false.

Comment: Cool, i just need to figure the max size for the char* and i'm set. thank you for the help!