# count and parse all the href links out of a html file

Tags: c, parsing

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336874/parsing-the-information-of-a-url-out-of-a-html-a-a-tags-in-c) I have been trying to parse the href strings out of a html file in order to send that string to the solution of my previous question.

this is what I have but it doesn't work...

```
void ParseUrls(char* Buffer)
{
    char *begin = Buffer;
    char *end = NULL;
    int total = 0;

    while(strstr(begin, "href=\"") != NULL)
    {   
        end = strstr(begin, "</a>");
        if(end != NULL)
        {
            char *url = (char*) malloc (1000 * sizeof(char));

            strncpy(url, begin, 100);
            printf("URL = %s\n", url);

            if(url) free(url);
        }

        total++;
        begin++;
    }

    printf("Total URLs = %d\n", total);
    return;
}
```

basically I need to extract into a string the information of the href, something like:

`<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a very helpful description of your program. Does it pass the compiler? Does it give any output?

Comment: no, it simple gets whatever random string it finds on `Buffer` and NOT what's in between `<a href.... </a>`

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of things wrong with this code.

- You increment begin only by one each time around the loop. This means you find the same href over and over again. I think you meant to move `begin` to after `end`?
- The strncpy will normally copy 100 characters (as the HTML will be longer) and so will not nul-terminate the string. You want `url[100]` = '\0' somewhere
- Why do you allocate 1000 characters and use only 100?
- You search for `end` starting with begin. This means if there's a  before the href="" you'll find that instead.
- You don't use `end` for anything.
- Why don't you search for the terminating quote at the end of the URL?

Given the above issues (and adding the termination of URL) it works OK for me.

Given

```
"<a href=\"/email_services.php\">Email services</a> "
```

it prints

```
URL = <a href="/email_services.php">Email services</a> 
URL = a href="/email_services.php">Email services</a> 
URL =  href="/email_services.php">Email services</a> 
URL = href="/email_services.php">Email services</a> 
Total URLs = 4
```

For the allocation of space, I think you should keep the result of the strstr of "href=\"" (call this `start` and then the size you need is `end - start` (+1 for the terminating NUL). Allocate that much space, strncpy it across, add the NUL and Robert's your parent's male sibling.

Also, remember href= isn't unique to anchors. It can appear in some other tags too.

Comment: Paul, thank you for the pointers. I used 100 just for testing purposes since I was getting all kind of things I just wanted to check the 1st 100 characters. In Any case I am allocation 1024 for the url. Do you have by any chance a snippet that might help me do this?

Comment: OK, would you mind explaining how can I fix the code I posted?

Comment: Assuming this is a learning exercise, I think you should have a go and update your question if you still can't crack it.

Comment: To give you a sample file to work with: just google something, extract the html source from google after you search and feed it to the function

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. It's what you should do :)

Comment: No, it's not a learning exercise. I am not a programmer, I am just caught in the need to do this for system administration so I'd appreciate if you could help me here.

Comment: OK, I do NOT understand what do I need to fix, otherwise I wouldn't ask

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I.e what's the reason you need to list the URLs? There may be better ways (for instance, this page will give you all the links on a page: http://linkleecher.com/)

Comment: As i said I am trying to parse the links out of an html formatted file. I know there are a gazillion ways to do it but since the program we are using for this purpose is in C I need to do it in C and since I am NOT a C programmer, I just learn it a long time ago, i need help. Not just `your code is not ok` or `why are you trying to do this` or `you are counting only 1` but actual code. I asked here because I coudlnt find the answer myself. is it so complicated to understand?

Comment: And why aren't you using the code AlistairG gave you for your previous question? It doesn't have most of the problems your code above does.

Comment: because my file has a fulllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll html set and i need to find the hrefs first before using that code

Comment: This isn't a site to get people to write your programs for you. I've given you a list of problems. If you don't yet have the C ability to address those, this isn't going to work, you'll just be back with more issues. Nothing about this is particularly difficult programming.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answer your qustion about this code, but it would probably be more reliable to use a C library to do this, such as [HTMLParser from libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html).

HTML parsing looks easy, but there are edge cases that make it easier to use something that is known to work than to work though them all yourself.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to use an external library to do something like this.